# Translate a basic auth request in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, basic-authentication

I'm working with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to make basic auth and I would know how to make the same in plain javascript. I have read some post on Stackoverflow but the solution doesn't work on my code. The body and res are returned undefined. However with request it works just fine.

Here my request snippet:

```
var url = "https://&&&&&&&&.api.&&&&&&&&.com/3.0";
var username = "&&&&&&&&";
var password = "&&&&&&&&";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

request.get( {
    url,
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
  }, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log('body : ', body);
  } );
```

I have tested the following solution:

**1:**

```
var request =  http.request({
    'url': 'url',
    'Authorization': 'anything:password'
}, 
function(error, res, body) {
    console.log('body : ', body);
},

function (response) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.body));
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    }) 
}

} 
request.end();
```

**2:**

```
var url = "&&&&&&&&";
var username = "&&&&&&&&";
var password = "&&&&&&&&";

var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

var http = require('http');

var request = http.request({
    url,
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
  }, function(error, res) {
      console.log('body : ', res);
  } );

  request.end();
```

Any hint would be great

Comment: I doubt that `1:` is valid JS code.

Comment: effectively I pass some typo  when reproduce the case

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing some response handling.

```
var http = require('http');

var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
var username = "test";
var password = "testPass";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

var options = {url, auth};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
var data = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk)
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    req.on('error', function(error) {
         // Error handling here
    });
});

req.end();
```

Also, if you're going to use Request with authentication, this may also help:   https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication